# Setting text on WpfEdit control throws pile of exceptions that are then caught -- Is this typical?

Tags: automated-testing, coded-ui-tests, exception

I'm doing some coded UI automation, and I've noticed something odd when debugging. When I try and set the text on a WpfEdit control `Control.Text = "foo"`, the system throws a gigantic pile of exceptions, most of which, but not all, or system.notsupportedexceptions.

It feels like this is probably bad, but since eventually the text gets set, so apparently all the exceptions are caught by the text setter; Perhaps the DLL is using exceptions for flow control internally or something like that. Is this just normal of Coded UI tests, or is there something I might be doing wrong?

---

While this isn't helpful to me, maybe it is to someone? This is what gets spat out into the output while stepping over that particular step in the debugger.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in UiaComWrapper.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Automation.ElementNotAvailableException' in UiaComWrapper.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotImplementedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility.dll
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\CustomMarshalers\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\CustomMarshalers.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Uia.dll
```